# How to implement pinch zoom in zoom out using javascript

Tags: javascript

am trying to implement pinch zoom in zoom out in js. I am almost there, as I have calculated how to detect pinch zoom in zoom out in js using touch events.
Does anyone know of a really good Javascript pinch-zooming algorithm? This is trickier than I had imagined, as you have to scale -AND- translate to keep the pinch zooming centered between your fingers.

And I want it to do pure translation when the user moves two fingers - kept an equal distance apart from each other - around the screen, i.e., this moving two fingers in unison should act like a single- finger "pan".

```js
<script>var dist1=0;
function start(ev) {
if (ev.targetTouches.length == 2) {//check if two fingers touched screen
dist1 = Math.hypot( //get rough estimate of distance between two fingers
ev.touches[0].pageX - ev.touches[1].pageX,
ev.touches[0].pageY - ev.touches[1].pageY);
}

}
function move(ev) {
if (ev.targetTouches.length == 2 && ev.changedTouches.length == 2) {
// Check if the two target touches are the same ones that started
var dist2 = Math.hypot(//get rough estimate of new distance between fingers
ev.touches[0].pageX - ev.touches[1].pageX,
ev.touches[0].pageY - ev.touches[1].pageY);
//alert(dist);
if(dist1>dist2) {//if fingers are closer now than when they first touched screen, they are pinching
alert('zoom out');
}
if(dist1<dist2) {//if fingers are further apart than when they first touched the screen, they are making the zoomin gesture
alert('zoom in');
}
}

}
document.getElementById ('zoom_here').addEventListener ('touchstart', start, false);
document.getElementById('zoom_here').addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);</script>


const img= document.getElementsByClassName(
                        zoom-img'
                    )[0] as HTMLElement
let imgHeight = targetTenMeterPistol.getBoundingClientRect()
                        .height
                    let imgWidth = targetTenMeterPistol.getBoundingClientRect()
                        .width

// cursors x and y position relative to viewport
                    let touchCursorX =
endMidPoint.x -
                        img.getBoundingClientRect().left
                    let touchCursorY =
endMidPoint.y -
                        img.getBoundingClientRect().top

                    // new origin to translate the img
                    // let newOriginX = 50
                    // let newOriginY = 50
                    let newOriginX = (touchCursorX / imgWidth) * 100
                    let newOriginY = (touchCursorY / imgHeight) * 100
inline css= transform:translate(scale) , transformOrigin: `${newOriginX}% ${newOriginY}% 0`
```

```html
<div class='zoom_here'></div>
```

Comment: `Does anyone know of a really good Javascript pinch-zooming algorithm?`... You might want to look at https://github.com/manuelstofer/pinchzoom rather than roll your own routine...

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in **Instagram** like pinch zoom feature there is a great example at [see -> with native Javascript code sample](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/vmorneau/r/pinch-and-zoom/pinch-and-zoom-js) that I used as starting point. The issue that I had with the script was that some of the images had existing transformation applied and the initial existing transformation was removed on **touchmove** due to the calculations as they were in the script that I found on the link.

**The issue:** I had some images with *transform translate(-50%,-50%)*, and with that in place they were centered on the screen, but when I start to scale the image with the existing translation in place it was moving the image to the right lower corner and starting the zooming process from there.

The code modified due to my needs (check for tagName IMG) with the additional calculations including **translateX**, **translateY** and **initialLoad** as global variables.

```
                      let imageElementScale = 1;

                      let start = {};

                      // Define a flag to keep track of initial load
                      let initialLoad = true;

                      // Define variables to keep track of the existing transform values
                      let translateX = 0;
                      let translateY = 0;

                      // Calculate distance between two fingers
                      const distance = (event) => {
                        return Math.hypot(event.touches[0].pageX - event.touches[1].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY - event.touches[1].pageY);
                      };

                      window.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
                          // Check if the element is an image
                          if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
                            if (event.touches.length === 2) {
                              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent page scroll

                              // Calculate where the fingers have started on the X and Y axis
                              start.x = (event.touches[0].pageX + event.touches[1].pageX) / 2;
                              start.y = (event.touches[0].pageY + event.touches[1].pageY) / 2;
                              start.distance = distance(event);
                            }
                          }
                        });

                        window.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
                          // Check if the element is an image
                          if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
                            if (event.touches.length === 2) {
                                  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent page scroll

                                  // Safari provides event.scale as two fingers move on the screen
                                  // For other browsers just calculate the scale manually
                                  let scale;
                                  if (event.scale) {
                                    scale = event.scale;
                                  } else {
                                    const deltaDistance = distance(event);
                                    scale = deltaDistance / start.distance;
                                  }
                                  imageElementScale = Math.min(Math.max(1, scale), 4);
                                  
                                  // Check if it's the initial load
                                  if (initialLoad) {
                                    // Get the existing transform style property for proper calculations
                                    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target);
                                    const existingTransform = style.getPropertyValue('transform');

                                    if(existingTransform.toString() !== "none") {
                                      const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                                      translateX = -rect.width / 2;
                                      translateY = -rect.height / 2;
                                    }
                                    initialLoad = false; // Update the flag to indicate initial load has occurred
                                  }

                                  // Calculate how much the fingers have moved on the X and Y axis
                                  const deltaX = (((event.touches[0].pageX + event.touches[1].pageX) / 2) - start.x) * 2; // x2 for accelerated movement
                                  const deltaY = (((event.touches[0].pageY + event.touches[1].pageY) / 2) - start.y) * 2; // x2 for accelerated movement

                                  // Combine the existing transform with the additional calculations
                                  const transform = `translate3d(` + (translateX + deltaX) + `px, ` + (translateY + deltaY) + `px, 0) scale(` + imageElementScale + `)`;
                                  event.target.style.transform = transform;
                                 
                                  event.target.style.WebkitTransform = transform;
                                  event.target.style.zIndex = "9999";
                                }
                          }
                        });

                        window.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
                          // Check if the element is an image
                          if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
                            // Reset image to it's original format
                            event.target.style.transform = "";
                            event.target.style.WebkitTransform = "";
                            event.target.style.zIndex = "";
                          }
                          //reset initialLoad and translateX and translateY needed to apply the existing transform on image
                          initialLoad = true;
                          translateX = 0;
                          translateY = 0;
                        });
```

Hope it helps someone.